# jQuery ajax POST params with ">" symbol problem

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to get a textbox value which contains ">" symbol using jQuery ajax with POST method, but I'm not getting the textbox value with ">" symbol. I'm tired of find a solution, please could anyone help me to fix this problem.

```
<div id="subi"><input type="textbox" id="test"><button onClick="sub()">Submit</button></div> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function sub() {
    var result = { content : $('#test').val() };
    alert(result);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'subi.php',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
        data: result,
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(html) {
            $('#subi').html(html);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: What *are* you getting instead?

Comment: If I post "test>hello>works" I get "test hello works" in php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you should do this server side(you should call htmlenties() on the string you are returning), just to check that this is the problem does this work?

```
success: function(html) {
    $('#subi').html(escape(html));
}
```

Comment: It's not working, let me explain.

when I post this value from the textbox "test>hello>how>works" I see this in the firebug "content=test%3Ehello%3Ehow%3Eworks" but in php I'm just getting this "test hello how works". I tried "htmlentitie", rawurldecode, 'urldecode' everything. Please help me.

Comment: have you tried the htmlspecialchars function http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: if  you use htmlentities server side remember NOT to use escape(html) but just $('#subi').html(html);

Comment: just now tried posting this "test<hello<oops" I get only "test" rest is truncated.

Answer (score 0):

try escape() function

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.escape